# Empty result from Query Explorer with `ga:adClicks` metrics and `ga:adPlacementUrl` dimension ?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I'm running some few test with Google analytics Query Explorer trying to build a request with :

- `ga:adClicks`
- `ga:adPlacementUrl`

but I got nothing in return, no error just an empty table. and Yes I've already check with the UI I have some numbers there.

Thanks !

Comment: are there any errors in the JavaScript Console? Also when you copy and past the **API query URI** into the browser url does it also say there are no results? Check the date range and view ID to make sure that you are making the same request. Also could you link the request your are making like this: `https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2017-01-16&end-date=2017-05-16&metrics=ga%3AadClicks&dimensions=ga%3AadPlacementUrl`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No error in the JavaScript Console. With the API query URI I don't have any results, only this `"totalsForAllResults":{"ga:adClicks":"0"}}`. Here is the request : `https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2017-06-01&end-date=2017-06-23&metrics=ga%3AadClicks&dimensions=ga%3AadPlacementUrl`. and the date range is also ok, I'm looking into the UI AdWords > Display Targeting > Placements reports.